# Linear Algebra book supplement to Axler

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation

I have been self-studying Linear Algebra from Linear Algebra done Right by Axler for the past one month. So far I haven't encountered Matrices/solving linear equations and the book doesn't seem to talk about Matrices at all (probably until the last chapter of Trace and Determinant) 
What book should I use as a supplement to Axler ?

Comment: Linear Algebra Done Right does not deal with solving systems of linear equations, but it does deal with matrices way before the last chapter (Chapter 10, Trace and Determinant). In particular, Section 3.C (in the third edition) is titled Matrices, Section 5.B is titled Eigenvectors and Upper-Triangular Matrices, and Section 5.C is titled Eigenspaces and Diagonal Matrices. Matrices also appear prominently in some sections that do not contain the word "Matrices" in their title (for example, Section 8.D on Jordan Form). Still, the main emphasis in the book is on linear maps, not matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're studying Linear Algebra done Right, there's a natural supplement:

[Linear Algebra done Wrong](https://sites.google.com/a/brown.edu/sergei-treil-homepage/linear-algebra-done-wrong), by Sergei Treil, freely available at that link. Unlike Axler, the author doesn't shy away from determinants, which I think is to its benefit.

(Also, I'm not entirely convinced that Axler doesn't talk about matrices... a matrix is just a linear transformation, represented in terms of a certain basis. It's how he proves a few theorems, IIRC...)

Answer (score 2):

I like Kenneth Hoffman's Linear Algebra [http://www.amazon.com/Linear-Algebra-Edition-Kenneth-Hoffman/dp/0135367972](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0135367972)

Answer (score 1):

Strang's "Introduction to Linear Algebra".
Axler does not use determinants, and Strang's book is more traditional than Axler's in that respect. So, with Strang's and Axler's textbooks he will gain spherical knowledge on the subject since he will be working on both sides.

Comment: What about this book?  How does it address the OP's concern for "a supplement to Axler"?

Comment: @hardmath Because Axler does not use determinants, and Strang's book is more traditional than Axler's in that respect. So, with Strang's and Axler's textbooks he will gain spherical knowledge on the subject since he will be working on both sides.

Comment: Strang is certainly a classic, particularly among somewhat applied math students/teachers.  My point is that your posted Answer is not even a complete sentence, and it could be improved by adding those observations from your Comment.

Comment: @hardmath yeah you are right, i will do so. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Shilov's Linear Algebra](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/048663518X). The first chapter is actually on determinants, and a lot of the content of the book builds on them, so you could say that its approach is the opposite of Axler's. Despite this and the fact that it's somewhat of an old book, a lot of people find it equally as illuminating as Axler. Not to mention, it contains about 400 pages of material despite being $13 (Dover edition), so it's quite worth the money.

[Contents](https://books.google.com/books?id=kyHCAgAAQBAJ&pg=PR7&source=gbs_selected_pages&cad=2#v=onepage&q&f=false)