# Linear algebra book for supplement material.

Tags: linear-algebra, book-recommendation

I’m studying linear algebra by Strang’s book, and I want to study more deeply about linear algebra. So I’m considering to buy a Axler’s linear algebra for supplement. Do you think the book “linear algebra done right” is fine for who is studying Strang’s style linear algebra? I’m not pretty used to prove theorems, so I wonder if it’s fine for like beginners.

Comment: Depends on your background really.. Are you a mathematics student?? If yes, done right is a good choice

Comment: And, as ususal, have a look at the right margin and the many good references on MSE, e.g., starting [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/828124/linear-algebra-book-supplement-to-axler?rq=1).

Comment: I’m studying math and econ. People said studying absract LA(they it is real one) directly can be difficult for beginner, and so they recommended me to study with Strang’s style book first.

Comment: I am starting to read David Lay's book : "Linear Algebra and It's Applications", although I can just go with Howard Anton "ELementary Linear Algebra". Serge Lang and Sheldon Axlers' are typical for Math majors wanting for rigors with theorems-proofs with all abstract things introduced from the start; that's why they begin with Vector Spaces in the 1st chapter. There is one book (an old book) that is quite rigorous : "Linear Algebra" by Kenneth Hoffman and Ray Kunze. Hoffman is from MIT, so we can expect a good text. It begins with Linear Equations, followed by Vector Spaces.